# Make two DIV elements with box-shadow not overlap thenselves

Tags: html, css

I have two <div> elements like so:

```css
.lorem {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 10px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.25);
}

.ipsum {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:15%;
    height:calc(100% - 50px);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 10px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="lorem">Lorem</div>
<div class="ipsum">Ipsum</div>
```

and i want to have something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oIRg.png).
Is there a way to do that without editing the already existing CSS rules?

Comment: ?? remove the box-shadow from the css rules if it bothers you. there is not much choice, you 'll have to edit your css, by removing or commenting that line or add an extra css selector with an higher specifity to reset the box shadow value. even rewriting the HTML will require CSS to set things in position unless you add an attribute style to reset box-shadow.(that's also CSS but not inside your CSS file;) )

Comment: Hi, my answer is a bit different to what it was before, take a look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for something like this:

```css
.lorem {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 10px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.25);
}

.ipsum {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:15%;
    height:calc(100% - 50px);
    box-shadow: -6px 22px 25px #ccc, 1px -6px 27px #fff;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="lorem">Lorem</div>
<div class="ipsum">Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! :)